# Widget layout error on saving

Tags: magento2.3, cache, widget

Testing a widget I created, I get a weird error when I try to set up the layout where the widget should appear.

After hitting the "save" button I get the following:

```
File "/http/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/" cannot be opened Warning!
fopen(/http/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/): failed to open stream: Is a directory
```

I notice this problem shows only when the caching system is set to use files instead of Redis or something else.

Any idea how can I fix it?

Developer mode is enabled, but I get not other error.

Answer (score 0):

Both environments were on "developer" mode, so the static files were not deployed.
Forcing the static files deployment fixed the problem error.

```
magento setup:static-content:deploy --force
```